# Rekit -React Buld Deployment

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have developed a react app using rekit studio. Once i build and after deploy it Rendering doesn't work. I create a normal react app and tried the same and its working. 
I suspense there is something wrong with the rekit redux architecture. have anybody tried this?

Please help me.

Comment: What error are you getting on the console?

Comment: Nothing.. Just the background picture loads and then says page not found